# Parsing CSV file with multi line fields using au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader.CSVReader

Tags: java, csv, parsing, opencsv

I want to parse a .csv file in java. Most of the lines (rows) in the file are following a typical .csv convention, but there are some cases which causes trouble. I am not actually sure if those cases are allowed or not in a csv-styled document. The biggest troublemaker is the multi-line cell with the text wrapped into quotes:

```
"text",12345,"text2"
"text",45678,"text2"
"text",23456,"text
accross multiple
lines"
```

So single cell in this case can be uniquely identified by quotes, so I guess it could work, but I cannot make `CSVReader` to parse it correctly. Any ides, how to set it up so it recognize this multi-line fields as a single field?

This is how I parse csv file in java:

```
try(FileInputStream fio = new FileInputStream(csvFile);
            InputStreamReader isr =  new InputStreamReader(fio, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(isr, ';', '"',true)){
        
            String[] line;
            reader.readNext(); //skip header
            while((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                updatedDataTable.add(processOneLine(line, csvFile));
            }

    }catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("Error", e);
    }
```

`CSVReader` has a small set of parameters in the constructor that can define parsing rules, but I cannot configure it in a way so it could tolerate the issue I described above.

Comment: Is `45678"` in second line of your example really correct? I can parse the csv correctly if I remove the double quote.

Comment: @samabcde Sorry, it was a typo. Good catch. Did you use some specific parameters in the `CSVReader` constructor?

Comment: Just create a reader by default, but I am using [newer version 5.5.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.opencsv/opencsv)

Comment: @samabcde Thanks! I updated the version and succeeded to configure it with `Builders` to work and parse correctly.